# Show a DIV if the URL contains a certain list strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to show/hide a certain DIV based on a list of URL's I have that need to display it. The problem Im running into is that these URL's may contain various parameters that I need to ignore and thats where Im running into trouble.

```
if(window.location.href == "http://www.google.com/example-one" || window.location.href=="http://www.google.com/example-two"){}
```

I need a more clean way to do this and just check if multiple strings exist somewhere in the URL.

Comment: You could use a loop here to check an array of URL's.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Are "example-one" and "example-two" what you want to ignore?   And always match to www.google.com?

Comment: The example is just my old code that checked for very specific URLS. Im looking for something that checks for any string I specify, doesnt ignore anything.

Answer (score 0):

What about passing your url into a function and then doing a partial search to see if it includes the part of the url you care about withoug the params.

```
function CheckURL(url) {
        var value = false;
        value = url.includes('google.com');
        // value = check 2
        // value = check 3
        return value;
    }
```

Or something similar but doing the work in a function that you can call and update as needed.

EDIT:

Based on question as example to hide a div.

```
        function CheckURL(url) {
            var x = document.getElementById("example");
            x.style.display = "none";

            var value = false;
            value = url.includes('google.com');
            // value = check 2
            // value = check 3
            if (value) {
                x.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
```

This hides it initially and then shows it if it meets the criteria.

Comment: Can you show an example of using this to show a div with an ID of #example?